# Android download attachments from webview

Tags: android

I went thro' all the posts but it's not working for me. Please help.

I am opening my email account in web view. So I want an ability to open attachments.

```
 wvA.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener()
        {
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType,
                    long size)
            {
                Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                viewIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), mimeType);

                try
                {
                    Log.i("Testing", "onDownloadStart");
                    startActivity(viewIntent);
                }
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex)
                {
                    Log.w("Testing", "Couldn't find activity to view mimetype: " + mimeType);
                }
            }
        });
```